# jQuery > Change getElementbyId.selectedIndex with option text value

Tags: php, jquery, dom

I've tried various thing to get to what I want but i'm in the woods completely.

Let me explain what is required.

I have a php variable containing a string equal to an option's value and I need to get the option corresponding to the string to be selected.

This is the select tag.

```
<select name="pos" id="pos">
<option value="">POS</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
<option value="LW">LW</option>
<option value="RW">RW</option>
<option value="LD">LD</option>
<option value="RD">RD</option>
<option value="G">G</option>
</select>
```

Example :

```
$string = "G";
```

Resulting select tag :

```
<select name="pos" id="pos">
<option value="">POS</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
<option value="LW">LW</option>
<option value="RW">RW</option>
<option value="LD">LD</option>
<option value="RD">RD</option>
<option value="G" selected>G</option>
</select>
```

Thanks a lot guys. I've been working on this forever and got no where.

Comment: Do you want this to be selected using jQuery (ie, no reloading of the page), or with PHP _REQUEST (ie submitting a form)?

Comment: It's actually a value I get from the GET. I used the jquery code of itspoma and added <?php echo $_GET[pos] ?> where the values go.

Comment: But your solution might be more appropriate, could you post it up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
// find required element
var el = jQuery('select#pos option[value="G"]')
// or
var el = jQuery('select#pos option').filter(function(){return jQuery(this).text()=="G"})

// set 'selected' attribute
el.attr("selected", "selected");

// find selected option
var el = jQuery('select#pos option:selected');
// get value
el.text()
```

Comment: it works. thank you very much.  stackoverflow == "Best community"